# Sed,awk or perl to capture lines between 2 patterns

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, grep

I have a file whose format is as follows:

```
pool1 {
  name:$NAME
  mode:$MODE
  address:$ADDRESS
  validity:$VALIDITY
     }

pool2 {
  name:$NAME
  mode:$MODE
  address:$ADDRESS
  validity:$VALIDITY
     }


pool3 {
  name:$NAME
  mode:$MODE
  version:$VERSION
  address:$ADDRESS
  validity:$VALIDITY
     }
```

I have a list of Addresses in another file.While I loop through the addresses file,I need to find the name of the respective address in this file.The problem is that the number of parameters within a pool is not fixed and keeps varying as is evident in pool 3 where a new parameter called version pops up..Hence I cannot do a normal grep for a address and then again grep for 2 lines above it.What I need is a command that will search for the occurrence of the line "address:$ADDRESS" and then find the occurrence of "name:$NAME" that occurs just prior to it..

Comment: Not very clear to me... Could you indicate the desired output?

Comment: i have a source file with 10 lines each having a unique address:$ADDRESS line.For every address:$ADDRESS,i need to find the name:$NAME in this file..

Comment: What is meant by $ADDRESS? In the above pool file, each pool have the same address if $ADDRESS is taken literally. So I guess it only makes sense if $ADDRESS is replaced by a real address.. Then the real file contains e.g. `address:123 Main Street` ?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$ cat file
pool1 {
  name:abc
  mode:$MODE
  address:foo
  validity:$VALIDITY
     }

pool2 {
  name:defghi
  mode:$MODE
  address:stuff
  validity:$VALIDITY
     }


pool3 {
  name:some other name
  mode:$MODE
  version:$VERSION
  address:bar
  validity:$VALIDITY
     }
$
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS=""; FS="\n" }
{
    split("",name2val)          # or delete(name2val) with gawk
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        line = $i
        gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",line)
        if ( split(line,tmp,/:/) == 2 ) {
            name2val[tmp[1]] = tmp[2]
        }
    }

    if ( name2val["address"] == tgt ) {
        print name2val["name"]
    }
}
$
$ awk -v tgt="stuff" -f tst.awk file
defghi
```

If not update your question with a better example and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You could use range patterns with awk, and within each range, print the `name` if the `address` matches. The address can of course be passed in via the command line using `-v`

```
awk -vaddress=address3 '/pool.*\{/,/\}/{if ($0 ~ /name/)name=$0; 
    if($0 ~ address) print name}' file.txt
```

Comment: is it awk -vaddress=address3 or awk -v address=address3...Also is address3 the value of the address i want to search ?

Comment: @Amistad, with GNU awk, both forms work with `-v`, YMMV depending on your version of awk. Yes, `address3` is the value of the address you need to search

Answer (score 1):

This might get you started:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict; 
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;


my $infile = 'in.txt';
open my $input, '<', $infile or die "Can't open to $infile: $!";

my (@pool, @address, @name, %hash);
while (<$input>){
    chomp;
    push @pool, $1 if ($_ =~ /(pool\d+)\s+\{/g);
    push @address, $1 if ($_ =~ /address:(.+)/g);
    push @name, $1 if ($_ =~ /name:(.+)/g);
}

push @{$hash{$pool[$_]} }, [$address[$_], $name[$_] ] for 0 .. $#pool;

print Dumper \%hash;
```

Which gives you a hash of arrays as such:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'pool1' => [
                       [
                         '$ADDRESS',
                         '$NAME'
                       ]
                     ],
          'pool2' => [
                       [
                         '$ADDRESS',
                         '$NAME'
                       ]
                     ],
          'pool3' => [
                       [
                         '$ADDRESS',
                         '$NAME'
                       ]
                     ]
        };
```

Now you can read in your file containing addresses and check to see if they exist in the above hash

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a good start is to just print the pool you are interested in, and that's trivial with `awk`.  For example:

```
awk '/\n  address:pattern/' RS= input-file
```

will only print those pools for which the address matches `pattern`.  By setting RS to the empty string, `awk` treats paragraphs (blocks of text separated by a blank line) as single records.  In the ideal world, it would be simple for awk to reparse that record into a dictionary and print the name, but it's really simpler to pipe the output to another `awk`:

```
awk '/\n  address:pattern/' RS= input-file | awk '/^  name/'
```